# How does ASP.net Identity access the database and is it the way i should be using?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

I am working on an ASP.net MVC website with Identity for security and login. I more or less know the basics of working with ASP.net Identity but a problem I have is that I have no idea of how it access the database form the connection-string.

To clarify my question: how does ASP.net Identity access the database and should I use the same method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asp.net Identity uses entity framework to connect to database and has it's own DbContext class, you can probably find it within `IdentityModel.cs`, its called `ApplicationDbContext`, its using Code-First approach to create the tables which are related to ASP.NET Identity, you can extend the properties by adding properties to ApplicationUser. if you want to change it's `ConnectionString` you can start by adding your connectionString to Its Base like below:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("YourConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the database you can use entity framework and use database first approach.

1. You have create the entitles from you table using command

   ```
   Scaffold-DbContext "Server=;Initial Catalog=dbname
   ;IntegratedSecurity=False;User ID=;Password=;
   ConnectTimeout=15;
   Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;
   ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entities -f
   ```
2. Command will create the context object for you and you can use same to access database.